# WPF: How do I bind a window's ShowInTaskbar property to code-behind value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to bind my window's "ShowInTaskbar" property to a definition in the code-behind, but it is not recognized. I also cannot programmatically assign the value in code-behind. I can only manipulate it by directly editing the xaml, which is not ideal in my situation.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    FontSize="14"
    Title="WPF Test"
    Name="Window"
    Icon="/Resources/icon.ico"
    Height="500" 
    Width="600" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" 
    StateChanged="Window_StateChanged" 
    Closing="Window_Closing"
    ShowInTaskbar="{Binding ShowInTaskbar}"
    >
        <Grid></Grid>
   </Window>
```

The property I have in the code-behind:

```
private bool _showInTaskbar
public bool ShowInTaskbar
{
     get
          {
               return _showInTaskbar;
          }
     set
          {
               _showInTaskbar = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("ShowInTaskbar");
          }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
Window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Why is my binding not being recognized? Or, how can I simply define it in code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. It was because I was using the same name as the window naturally inherits. Once I changed my property to "ShowIconInTaskbar" I bound it and it functions properly.

Comment: Nice find. Did it raise any warning? Normally C# warns about this specific case, suggesting using either `new` or `override`.

Comment: Nope, no warning, which is why it was so confusing.